# Counterexample for which $H^{i}(Y,\mathcal{F})$ and $H^{i}(X,f_{*}\mathcal{F})$ are not isomorphic.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

I came across the following result.

Let $X$ be a separated $k$-scheme that admits an open covering of spectra of finitely generated $k$-algebras. Let $f:Y\rightarrow X$ be a morphism of schemes which is affine and of finite type. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_{Y}$-module. Then we have natural isomorphisms of $k$-vectorspaces 
$$H^{i}(Y,\mathcal{F})\cong H^{i}(X,f_{*}\mathcal{F}).$$

I would like to see an example of a morphism $f:Y\rightarrow X$ of separated $k$-schemes and a quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_{Y}$-module  $\mathcal{F}$ for which there exists an integer $i$ such that 
$$H^{i}(Y,\mathcal{F})\ncong H^{i}(X,f_{*}\mathcal{F}).$$

Comment: Take $X$ the spectrum of $k$, $Y=\mathbb{P}^1_k$, $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{O}_Y(1)$ and $i=1$, I think.

Comment: @Mindlack Not $\mathcal{O}_Y(1)$, this sheaf has no cohomology, but $\mathcal{O}_Y(-2)$ for instance. Otherwise this is a good counter-example.

Comment: @Roland: Thank you for the correction!

Comment: The "high level" view (perhaps too high-level!) of this is that the Leray spectral sequence has $E_2$ page $H^p(X,R^qf_*\mathcal{F})$ and converges to $H^{p+q}(Y,\mathcal{F})$ - in the case when $f$ is affine, all higher direct images vanish and the spectral sequence degenerates at the $E_2$ page. So all one needs to do is find a non-affine morphism and a sheaf with nonvanishing higher direct image, aka nonzero cohomology.

Answer (score 1):

To close this post I repeat here the counter example Mindlack and Roland gave in the comments.

Take $X = \operatorname{Spec}(k)$ and $Y=\mathbb{P}_{k}^{1}$ and $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{O}_{Y}(-2)$. Then one can find for $i=1$ that we indeed do not have an isomorphism.